# "Full Access" permission doesn't permit OWA access

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

What troubleshooting should I do if the "Full Access" permission doesn't allow me to access a mailbox via OWA?

I'm accessing the mailbox using the url:

```
https://owa.yoursite.com/owa/other.user@yourdomain.com
```

Comment: You should tell us how, exactly, your trying to access this mailbox via OWA, because it sounds like you're doing it wrong (or you don't actually have full access permissions).

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking why the mailbox doesn't show up in OWA like it does in Outlook, that's because OWA doesn't work that way.

To access a mailbox other than the one associated with your AD account, use https://owa.yoursite.com/owa/other.user@yourdomain.com and then log in with your account.

Comment: This is exactly how I'm trying to access the mailbox, but am unable to.  I went into EMC and gave the second user "Full Access Permission"

Answer (score 1):

1. Issue the command `get-mailboxpermission -identity user` where user would be the mailbox you've granted full access to. Ensure the account you'd like to access the mailbox with is listed in that group and Full Access is the access rights
2. In EMC verify that both mailboxes have "Outlook Web App" set as enabled in the mailbox properties
3. Ensure you're trying to access the mailbox by clicking on name of the Accessing Mailbox (in the top right of the screen) and you're selecting "Open" and typing the mailbox you're trying to access. Note that the mailbox will not show up on the left hand side of the OWA as it does with an Outlook 2010 client
4. Set up an Outlook 2010 mail profile with the user's account that you'd like to access the other account with (not the mailbox you've granted the full access rights on) to see if the other account is listed on the left-hand side. This will isolate if the problem is with the permissions or with OWA.

Answer (score 0):

Users should make sure they are entering the primary SMTP address of the alternate user.. not the secondary alias which did not work in my testing.